# On Crete or in Crete?

Tags: prepositions

Which variant is correct? I would say "on Crete" ("ON an island", the general rule):

> "I live on Crete".

(At the same time, I assume that in the case of Cyprus both variants are correct since Cyprus is an island and a state. Crete is not a state.)

Please, correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting question.  Yes, if there is a greater entity then it is **in**, unless the island is split e.g. St Martin

> I live **on** Captiva Island.
>   I live **on** Sanabel Island.
>   I live **on** Lido Island in Miami.
>   I live **on** St Martin.
>   I live **on** Ile de la Cité
>   I live **in** Manhattan.  *(borough)*
>   I live **on** the Big Island, not Maui.
>   I live **in** Japan.  *(state)*
>   I live **in** Mauritius.  *(state)*
>   I live **in** the Bahamas. *(state)*
>   I live **in** Puerto Rico.  *(state)*